# Javascript: "var" related doubts

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <button class="btn">aa</button>

    <script>
        var aBtn=document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

        var i = 0;

        while(i<aBtn.length){

            aBtn[i].onclick = function(){
                console.log(i);
                    // 1  ??????
            }            
            i++
        }

    </script>
```

I'd like to know why the console outcome is 1 in the end, instead of 0.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044285 (or, better yet, use `.forEach` with `.querySelectorAll` to get the index)